# Mapping Windows 7 network drive to Sharepoint caused large performance hit

Tags: windows-7, networking, performance, sharepoint

Moved work files from a local network to Sharepoint. I wanted to interact with the file structure in the same way I had previously. I inherited a workflow that stored and used files from several places so I often have 4-5 file explorer windows open and I don't want the cognitive load of downloading from Sharepoint and having to re-upload at the end of the day.

Once I mapped the drive my memory usage shot up to 82%, and there is a noticeable slow-down in system performance.

How can I either: troubleshoot to determine that the mapped network drive is causing the slow-down OR tweak settings to improve performance.

Comment: What kind of network bandwidth is available between you and the SharePoint server?  Can you go try opening Internet Explorer, go to Tools :: Internet Options :: Connections, click LAN settings, and uncheck Automatically detect settings... and let us know if it makes a difference.

Comment: @Ƭᴇcʜιᴇ007 disabling `Automatically Detect Settings` didn't change anything. My internet connection is 5 down, 5.5 up. Can I determine bandwidth to sharepoint specifically through the ping command?